# How to create big organization charts like google maps?

Tags: sitemap, data-visualization, tiles, orgchart, mindmap

I don't know javascript (unfortunately) and I'd like to make a mindmap-like "organization chart" similar to [this one](http://www.mindomo.com/view?m=d810818269d541a6a9d58d43a383cce5): 
[image: Mindomo organization chart screenshot]

This map should have an ability to zoom-in and zoom-out similar to google maps, and the ability to arbitrarily connect nodes. So it is more like a free graph, not like an ordinal tree. Mindomo makes this pretty well, but it is commercial and flash-oriented.

Does anybody know of a similar solution?

My research pointed me out that this could be a svg sketch, possibly generated offline, or maybe something using canvas. A click on the node should redirect to some web location.

Google maps is good because it also hides some details, and so should do this graph map in zoomed out projection.

Comment: Thank you Jason for edit and corrections of my poor English.

Answer (score 1):

A few important questions:
Do you need this generated in real time based on some underlying dataset?
Aside from zooming, should the user be able to manually open/close nodes?

You can manually generate this simply using some free tools:

- [MindMeister](http://www.mindmeister.com/)
- [xmind](http://www.xmind.net/)
- [freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

although non-traditional, can you consider using Prezi?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I already know those programs you proposed, and I would rather prefer some quick-simple-and-dirty solution just to use in plain web page. I would also avoid commercial services or standalone programs.

Comment: sorry, I think quick-and-dirty is not possible without a commercial service or standalone program, no?